# Straight things on Grassmanians

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, definition, grassmannian

I am new to Grassmanian, so this question may be too easy. But I didn't find it in any books I know.

When we talk about Grassmanian, it should not be only a manifold or a variety. At least I think we can talk about the straight things on it. For example, let $V$ be a fixed linear space, we have the following two natrual ways to define straight things on the Grassmanian $Gr(m,V)$.

(a) Use the natural corresponding between $Gr(m,V)$ and $Gr(m+k,V)$, we can define a $k$-plane on $Gr(m,V)$ to be any element in $Gr(m+k,V)$.

(b) Use the Plücker embedding $Gr(m,V)\hookrightarrow \mathbb P^N$, we can pullback the hyperplane line bundles $\mathcal O(1)$ on $\mathbb P^N$ to define the hyperplanes on $Gr(m,V)$, and then define $k$-planes to be the intersection of $l$ hyperplanes, where $l=dim(Gr(m,V))-k$.

I want to know are these two defintions consistent? And where can I find references about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. That's a good question. Why do you think that these two might be the same? Did you check the case where $V = \Bbb R^2$ and $m = 1$ by hand?

Comment: @JohnHughes Hi. I just think these two are both natural, so they should be the same. In your case $Gr(1,2)$ is projective itself, so the Plücker embedding is trivial, thus the two definitions are consistent.

Comment: Limes and bananas are also both natural, but not the same. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes I mean, the lines on a Grassmanian should be a natural notion, so at least we should define it in (a) or (b). If the two are not consistent, then a counter example would be convincing to me.

Comment: I have no idea whether they're the same, and I knew what you were saying. I just didn't find it compelling enough evidence to make me get excited about thinking about the problem. But someone else probably will -- we'll see!

Comment: @JohnHughes Ok, I find they are not the same. There are various way to see it. For example, in the definition (a) two points in a Grassmanian do not determine a line. Also the definition (a) only produces planes in certain dimensions, much fewer compared to the dimension of the Grassmanian. I think the definition of (b) looks more reasonable.

Comment: Excellent! Perhaps you can go ahead and write up a detailed answer to your own question, which is a great thing to do. You can accept it (which won't get you any 'points'), and others can then upvote it (which will, if you care!). Better still, it won't leave yet another unanswered question floating around MSE. And others, stumbling on your question as they search, will instantly see where the answer lies.

Comment: @JohnHughes I have posted and accepted it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, for general cases, (a) is not a good definition. More precisely, for $Gr(m,V)$ where $m>1$, two points on $Gr(m,V)$, which correspond to two $m$-dimensional linear subspaces of $V$, do not contain in any "lines" on $Gr(m,V)$, which correspond to $(m+1)$-dimensional linear subspaces of $V$, unless the very special case that the two $m$-dimensional linear subspaces have a codimension one intersection. Also, let $n=dim(V)$, then definition (a) only produces $k$-planes with $k=0,1,\ldots,n-m$, which are much fewer compared to $dim(Gr(m,V))$ which equals $m(n-m)$.

I think (b) looks like a sutible definition. By simple computations, one can show that in definition (b), a (at least some, see below) hyperplane on $Gr(m,V)$ contains all the $m$-dimensional linear subspaces of $V$ which are vertical to a certain $m$-dimensional linear subspace. More precisely, let $x_i$'s be the standard coordinates of $V$, then the Plücker embedding $\mathbb P^N$ has the standard coordinates $x_{i_1}\wedge \ldots\wedge x_{i_m}$'s, and a hyperplane will correspond to 
$$\sum a_Ix_{i_1}\wedge \ldots\wedge x_{i_m}=0.$$
 For the hyperplane $x_1\wedge\ldots\wedge x_m=0$ on $\mathbb P^N$, it can be restricted to give a hyperplane on $Gr(m,V)$ which contains all $m$-dimensional linear subspace of $V$ vertical to $x_1\wedge\ldots\wedge x_m$. For a hyperplanes $\sum a_Ix_{i_1}\wedge \ldots\wedge x_{i_m}=0$ not decomposable, their geometric interpretations are still not clear to me. Even I am not sure will they concide with the hyperplanes we already get, or it will produces (much) more new hyperplanes. Or maybe we should only define hyperplanes on $Gr(m,V)$ to be the decomposible ones? It would be very nice if someone knew this could give a comment.